# Letter spacing difference in android and IOS

Tags: fonts, shopify, custom-font

I am working on  Shopify website and I am facing an issue,

I am using custom Font (Sofia Pro) and using Fontio App to assign the custom fonts to my different tags on the website.

The issue resides in the following images

Image shows the title of the website on PC

[image: 1]

Image shows the title of the website on IOS

[image: 2]

Image shows the title of the website on Android

[image: 3]

There is difference in letter spacing , However the code used for the header is as follows :
`h1 { font-weight: 600 !important; letter-spacing: -1px !important; }`

The letter spacing is set to -1px !important to insure overwriting every other styling.

What is the solution to avoid having different letter spacings between different platforms?

Thanks,
Sahel Wahdain